# SSIS - Data Conversion from DT_STR to int

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, bids

How to apply the below transformation in SSIS data flow task

```
cast(gift_amount as int)/100
```

In Derived Column Transformation Editor, I am unable to change the data type. It gives `0xC0049064` error upon giving `typecast` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acieve this using a `script component`

1. Add a `Script Component`
2. Mark `gift_amount` as input column
3. Add an output column of type Decimal or float (ex `outColumn`)
4. Add the following code: *(using vb.net)*

   ```
   If Not Row.giftamount_IsNull AndAlso
      Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Row.giftamount) Then

       Row.outColumn = CDec(CInt(Row.giftamount) / 100)

   Else

       Row.outColumn_IsNull = True

   End If
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You should try

```
((DT_I4)gift_amount)/100
```

Also, in the Derived Column Editor window, you can add other types of casts - take a look through some of those options in the upper right hand part of the editor.

[image: ssis dco editor]